# SIP initiate call to two parties and merge

Tags: sip, jain-sip

I am newbie using SIP protocol, I googled alot to find an answer for the following but unfortunately I didn't find an answer.

Is it possible using SIP protocol to initiate call from a SIP server to two clients, and then merge the two calls?

Comment: Sure, you typically need a combination of SIP & Media server. SIP server to take care of the call setup (signaling) and media server to connect your clients and 'broadcast' the media streams effectively realizing a conference. You can have a look at Restcomm Connect for that, which is open source and provides both aforementioned components. Also, it is fully programmable: you can initiate the calls via REST calls from a browser or whatever else, or in the opposite direction you can create a conference Restcomm App, where your clients dial the same Restcomm SIP number and that's it.

Comment: Feel free to ask more specific questions either here or on Restcomm forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/restcomm there's a vibrant community that can help you. Here are some interesting links: GitHub project https://github.com/RestComm/Restcomm-Connect and Docker quickstart, which is the easiest way to deploy it locally: http://documentation.telestax.com/connect/configuration/docker/Restcomm%20-%20Docker%20Quick%20Start%20Guide.html#restcomm-docker

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. The conferencing servers heavily use the concept of initiating calls to end users and then merging them to a conference session. You can look into code of Asterisk IPPBX or other similar implementations to get an idea.